# Using the function mixedcase

Tags: python

I'm new to coding, I'm using python, and I'm trying to make my input gives an output in mixed case, but it is returning an error.
Here is my line of code

```py
transport = input("what type of transport do you take to school? ")
transport = transport.mixedcase()
print(transport)
```

The error I get is object has no attributes in mixed case

Comment: Because string objects have no method called `mixedcase`.

Comment: What output are you expecting? Did you perhaps mean [`.title`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) which would turn `'car'` into `'Car'`?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I got it now

Answer (score 0):

Make a for loop through the word and add the upper and lower case letters to a new string

```
word = "word"
copy = ''
low = False
for i in word:
    if low == False:
        copy += i.upper()
        low = True
    else:
        copy += i.lower()
        low = False

print(copy)
```

you can also create is as a function

```
def mixedcase(word):
    copy = ''
    low = False
    for i in word:
        if low == False:
            copy += i.upper()
            low = True
        else:
            copy += i.lower()
            low = False
    print(copy)

mixedcase("what type of transport do you take to school? ")
```

so you can call it

Comment: the low = False alternates between going in the lowecare is or the uppercare

Comment: You don't need more than one line to do that. `return "".join((char.upper() if n%2 else char.lower() for n, char in enumerate(word)))`

Comment: or like that but it's not that easy to understand it like this for a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to "mixed case" is a bit vague.  If by mixed case, you mean to have the first character of your input capitalized, then you could use the "capitalize()" function as follows.

```
transport = input("what type of transport do you take to school? ")
transport = transport.capitalize()
print(transport)
```

Here is a sample of the input and output.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Mixed$ python3 Mixed.py 
what type of transport do you take to school? bus
Bus
```

Give that a try if that's the type of result you are after.